# What is the correct pronouns to refer to "some"?

Tags: pronouns

In the following sentence:

> Some have a headache today.

I would like to express it using a pronoun. For example:

> Some have pain in *their* head today.

However, I'm not sure what is the correct pronoun to use here. It *their* the correct pronoun here or should I use another one?

EDIT: By "some", I mean "some people".

Comment: Depending on the context, it might be more natural to specify "some people". Plain "some" works best if you have established a set of people you're talking about (e.g., "Many of the kids in the class went home sick. Some have a headache today.").

Answer (score 0):

While it is not incorrect to say "Some have pain in their head today".  It doesn't improve on the first sentence "Some have a headache today", since a headache is a pain in one's head.

The tense should be corrected. One of "Some had", "Some are having" or "Some will have" would work better than the simple present. And a better choice of verb  "Some will suffer from a headache".

However, changing to "pain in their head" does nothing to improve the expression.

If you actually want to talk about another body part, there would be nothing wrong with  "some will have a pain in their chest today", for example.

Comment: Yes but there are other body parts that don't have the fixed noun like *headache*, right? Maybe my question is not good...

Comment: "some will have pain in their head today"  Shouldn't it be "in their heads" ?